# Grid view item's

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using `GridView` in my application , I set the number of columns to 2 it is working correctly but if the number of items in the grid are greater than 8 items it start repeating the first item.

I want to reach 14 items without repeating any item. Thanks!

Here's my gridview xml

```
 <GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="160dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/View1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

![this is screen shot ,after it reach (cotact 8) it repeat (cotact 1), (cotact 2) ...etc][1]
this is my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View v;


        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon_launcher, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text); 
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);              
            LinearLayout icon = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_launcher);

            //icon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(203,200));
            ib.setScaleType(ib.getScaleType().FIT_XY);          
            ib.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
            ib.setFocusable(false);
            ib.setClickable(false);          
            ib.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mThumbIds.get(position)));

            tv.setText(mTextsIds.get(position));
 } else

        {
            v = (View) convertView;


        }


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Paste your adapter code.

Comment: It must be related to your gridview adapter code. May be in view reusing.

Comment: ok , I paste my adapter @ Michał Z @ Yvan RAJAONARIVONY

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.icon_launcher, null);


        } 

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        LinearLayout icon = (LinearLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.icon_launcher);

        // icon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(203,200));
        ib.setScaleType(ib.getScaleType().FIT_XY);
        ib.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        ib.setFocusable(false);
        ib.setClickable(false);
        ib.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mThumbIds.get(position)));

                tv.setText(mTextsIds.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your Adapter is reusing the views. And in your code you only get the controls when the **convertView** is null (gets created).

---

After some items android starts reusing the views (convertView is not null anymore) and your **getView** method doesn't set the textview etc.

---

You should set the content (textview etc.) outside your "if (convertView == null)" method like @Glenn suggested.